# How can I protect my website from users who upload copyrighted material?

Tags: web-hosting, protection

I have a small website that hosts text content that user can upload (short novels, essays, other personal work). How do I protect the website from people who might upload copyrighted content (i.e., material that is not their intellectual property, copy-pasted works of other authors, ...)?

Of course, I have already a system in place that "probes" the material's content, so as to disallow anything that is not strictly text. However, there is no way to check whether the given text contains (or is) copyrighted material.

Does anyone have experience with such situations? How would a webmaster go about protecting their site?

Comment: We get this question a lot! The simple answer is to place a button or link on each and every page that allows a person to report copyright violations. Once you get a report, take the offending material down immediately. You need to be timely on this so check daily. Responsiveness is a good defense. As well, make sure you have a prominent notice when people post content. You want to be clear to the OP that the content must be fully owned by the poster and that they are granting permission to host the content. Get a lawyer to write this if you can. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks a lot for your answer! If you make it into an answer, I will accept it